# Correct Verb Tense

Tags: verbs, tenses

I am writing a software description in which I am explaining the actions the end user can take with regard to his/her assumed previous actions.

Is it grammatically correct to use present perfect for the previous actions (has replied ) (has posted) in two sentences below ?

1. The user can make further replies to any message he/she **has already replied to**.
2. The user can delete any message he/she **has posted**.

Comment: When I read, **delete any messages s/he _has_ posted**, then I assume that the user may not be able to **delete any messages s/he _had_ posted** (say in the previous login session or a month ago). Using the past perfect tense here would remove the ambiguity.

Comment: Tangential to your actual question, but a better way to phrase this would be: 1. The user can make further replies to any message to which he/she has already replied.

Comment: This is known as the (fallacious) "rule" _Don't end a sentence with a preposition._

Comment: Your title is currently **completely generic**! Please [edit] your title to make it something more specific.

Comment: Also, don't write *he/she*, just write *they*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both sentences use the present perfect tense correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, there are questions as to the appropriateness of the present perfect. I see  a way to totally bypass the issue here:

*The user can make further replies to **any message already replied to [by him/her]**.*

*The user can delete any **of his/her already-posted messages***